# Define for constants like in C++

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a file which imports a number of functions from dll, before every function I must put:

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

But it is boring and code becomes longer -> harder to understand, in **C** I can use define like this:

```
#define DLL_IMPORT [DllImport(...)]
```

What can I do in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of luck. The [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute is sealed, so you can't derive an instance and default the parameters, and C# has no macro processor to allow you to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/) to make your job a little easier. This tool automatically generates managed p/invoke declarations (in C# or VB) from native signatures. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx